# Enviar metodo post a google app script

Tags: javascript, post, google-apps-script, fetch

estoy teniendo una duda que quisas es algo simple pero excede mis conocimientos
Tengo una app en appscript , donde por medio de un POST logro insertar datos en un sheet
[image: error]

ahora cuando lo quiero hacer desde js con este codigo :

```
fetch(scriptURL, { method: 'POST', body: new FormData($formBudget)})
                .then(response => 
                  console.log("Enviado")
                  )
                .catch(error => console.error('Error!', error.message))
                  console.log(" NO Enviado")

            })
```

Obtengo este error

[image: error2]

Puede ser que el error venga por que en el codigo no le estoy mandando un JSON?

mis conocimientos no llegan a tanto , pero eso es lo que deduje

por lo que tengo entendido new FormData da un objeto que es diferente al JSON que mande con postman

EDITO Agregando mi cod.gs:

```
var vbook =  SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx-fr0dZFjzYJcK8NI/edit#gid=0");
var sheet = vbook.getSheetByName("Sheet1");


function doPost(e){
  // var action = e.parameter.action;
  // if (action == "addUser"){
  return addData (e);
  // }
}

function doGet() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
  return html.setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
}



function uploadFiles(data)
{
 var file = data.myFile;
 var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
 var createFile = folder.createFile(file);
 return createFile.getUrl();
}

function addData (e){
var data = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
sheet.appendRow([data.name,data.age,data.mobile,data.email]);
return ContentService.createTextOutput("success").setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT);
}
```

Comment: CORS es algo que se soluciona desde el servidor, no desde el cliente. Tu no tienes control sobre el servidor (en este caso Google) entonces no puedes hacer nada. No puedes llamar a ese script directamente desde tu página con Javascript.
Lo que si puedes hacer para solventar el problema es crear tu propio servidor, que reciba los datos y sea el servidor el  que haga la peticion a google (y sobre ese servidor tu si tienes control)... por ejemplo tener una ruta `https://miserver.com/ejecutar-script` y sea ese endpoint el que haga el post a google

Comment: CORS es una limitación impuesta desde el navegador (pero controlada por el servidor), si usas tu propio server para hacer la peticion no usas un navegador, por eso te puedes saltar la restriccion de CORS si creas tu propio server

Comment: @Pipe POSTMAN hace eso que me recomendaste hacer verdaD?

Comment: Es similar, POSTMAN no usa un navegador, por eso tampoco aplican las restricciones para el.

Comment: Agrega un [mcve] (include el doPost de Google Apps Script y un html/javascript que haga la llamada POST)

Comment: @Rubén ahi agrege el code.gs , el html / js esta publicado como la fetch

Comment: Tal vez valga la pena mencionar que [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS), básicamente, es un mecanismo de seguridad basado en la **cabecera** de la petición donde el **server** le indica al navegador desde cuáles dominios tiene permitido procesar el acceso a los recursos. Básicamente, si tu dominio **no está en esa lista**, no tienes permitido ver/interactuar con los recursos.

Comment: Alejandro: En un comentario a una respuesta parece que mencionas que el HTML lo publicas usando Google Apps Script, si esto es así, entonces el doGet si es necesario y haría falta el archivo `index.html`

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Esto lo puedes solucionar utilizando un servidor intermedio para comunicar tu aplicación front con tu appscript y en tu propio servidor solucionar el tema de los cors (con express por ejemplo se puede lograr), por otra parte puedes utilizar [Google Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api) y tal vez de ese modo te puedas ahorrar lo del servidor intermedio.

Comment: El problema es que estoy corriendo el html desde el propio appscript, hay alguna forma de hacer un server intermedio ahi?